# How can I create a FactoryGirl factory for a Product that belongs_to a User?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

I have read the FactoryGirl documentation, but I can't seem to figure this out. I know that it must be simple.

Here is my setup:

```
Rails 3.2.6
User has_many Products


FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :product do
    sequence(:identifier, 1000) {|n| "ABC#{n}" }
  end
end
```

This fails because there must be a user_id associated with the Product. In my tests, I am creating a user during login. So my tests have access to the user object. I just don't know how to pass the user object in to the Product factory using FactoryGirl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already have a User factory (i.e `factory :user do`) you can add the following line in your `:product` factory:

```
association :user
```

That will automatically create a user factory (as defined) and assign it to your product.

When you create the object in your test though, you can still do something like:

```
FactoryGirl.create(:produce, user: some_user)
```

in order to assign a different user variable, because the Factory sees the association from the line you just added.

Hope this helps.